# Git how to squash all the commit

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I have try to use `git rebase -i HEAD~3` to squash all the commit. But git throw below error, for the commit `HEAD~3` is not exist.

> fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'

```
$ git log --oneline
7cabc02 (HEAD -> master) fix bug
26a9c03 fix bug
59fe21b record video process
```

So, how can I squash all the commit to one.

Comment: Try to apply the `--root` key: `git rebase -i --root`.

Comment: Another option: `git reset --soft 59fe21b && git commit --amend --no-edit`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+all+commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to squash those three commits, including the first one, is to run the following command:

```sh
git rebase -i --root master
```

Please note that the `--root` option was introduced in [git version 1.7.12](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.12.txt#L59).

Running this command will open the interactive dialog to perform the rebase and that dialog will include your first commit. In that dialog, leave the first commit as `pick` and set the other two to `squash`. Save and quit your editor to perform the operation.

```
pick 59fe21b record video process
squash 26a9c03 fix bug
squash 7cabc02 fix bug

# Rebase 7cabc02 onto 59fe21b (3 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have two commits older than your HEAD, so `HEAD~3` indeed doesn't exist. If you want to (interactively) rebase all of them, you can (should!) use `HEAD~2`:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

You can also explicitly use a commit hash:

```
git rebase -i 59fe21b
```

Comment: this will result in 2 commit, not noe.